# How to define a xpath for the following elements

Tags: css, xpath

I tried

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='container_results']/li[1]/div[1]/a/img")).click();`

Element which i used is

```
<img class="lazy" alt="" src="http://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/Levi/clothing/392920000-front-grid.jpg" data-original="http://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/Levi/clothing/392920000-front-grid.jpg" style="display: block;">
```

But it worked fine once and again it's not working.

please help to find out the exact xpath or using id for the above question.

Comment: For the above question i used it from the following element which is <img class="lazy" alt="" src="http://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/Levi/clothing/392920000-front-grid.jpg" data-original="http://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/Levi/clothing/392920000-front-grid.jpg" style="display: block;">

Comment: please provide the complete html fragment for your question.